# How to attach debugger to hardhat chai tests in Vscode and use Typescript breakpoints?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ethereum, ethers.js, hardhat

I know I can put `console.log`s in Chai tests and get them printed in console. However, I want to know how can I put a regular breakpoint (or `debugger;` statement) in Vscode, and hit it, and debug as usual with stepping, evaluation, viewing local variables etc.

How do I *truly* debug hardhat chai test with breakpoints in Vscode (instead of `console.log`s)?

Comment: I have started learning hardhat and now hit a point need to debug the chai tests instead of console.log. Did you @Can Poyrazoğlu get any further on the same?

Comment: can't you just set breakpoints in the typescript code and include the `npx hardhat test` command in a [launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) of vscode?

Comment: @philipphutterer I did try to have that command, but then the control did not stop the breakpoint.  It is a silly mistake but completely valid for a newbie like me. Finally found the answer in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71880965/7394630). This will do for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugger in VSCode I have following in my `.vscode/launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Hardhat individual test",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "testhh",
                "${workspaceFolder}/test-hardhat/<testFile>.ts"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`testhh` is a name of a script in my `package.json`, which look like `"testhh": "yarn hardhat test --no-compile"`.
Debugger can then be run via `Run and Debug` menu.

To add a bit of context to script. I run individual test files with yarn `testhh test-hardhat/<testFile>.ts`

Comment: Yup. I've also tried this with a custom script by having my yarn script with the name and putting runtimeArgs as [`myscriptname`] and it also worked.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the comments section above, I was in a similar situation, unable to have a breakpoint on chai tests.

There could be multiple ways to debug and I will keep updating the answer as and when I find a new one.

1. Deploy the contract in the local HardHat node and test as explained in the [Theread Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71880965/7394630).
2. This is the closest answer I came across is as explained in [LinkedIn post comment](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6939529919374721024?commentUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28activity%3A6939529919374721024%2C7023985066213044224%29&replyUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28activity%3A6939529919374721024%2C7024011179157045248%29&dashCommentUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afsd_comment%3A%287023985066213044224%2Curn%3Ali%3Aactivity%3A6939529919374721024%29&dashReplyUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afsd_comment%3A%287024011179157045248%2Curn%3Ali%3Aactivity%3A6939529919374721024%29). 
   a) Place a breakpoint in the typescript test code. 
   b) Run the following command  in **Javascript Debug Terminal**. 
   `hardhat test [testfoldername]\[testfile].ts` \